# Как сделать выборку отдельных полей в LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Начал работать с LINQ, пока не понимаю некоторых очевидностей

```
DataClasses1DataContext alldata = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            vocabularyDataGrid.ItemsSource = from word in alldata.Words
                                             orderby word.word
                                             select (word);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в выборку попали только некоторые из полей, в частности word, translation, Types, 
как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
select (word.word, word.translation, word.Types);
```

не работает

Comment: `select new { word.word, word.translation, word.Types }`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Удивительно, но, когда я пытался написать это - оно не работало. Скопипастил и заработало

Answer (score 0):

```
vocabularyDataGrid.ItemsSource = from word in alldata.Words
                                             orderby word.word
                                             select new { word.word, word.translation, word.Types };
```